# barnyard2 for snort permission denied

Tags: centos, linux-networking, snort, intrusion-detection, barnyard2

I installed barnyard2 for snort, but when i run command below this error appear.

```
[root@localhost snort]# barnyard2 -c /etc/snort/barnyard2.conf -d /var/log/snort/ -f snort.log -w /etc/snort/bylog.waldo /etc/snort/gen-msg.map /etc/snort/sid-msg.map -C /etc/snort/classification.config 
Running in Continuous mode

    --== Initializing Barnyard2 ==--
Initializing Input Plugins!
Initializing Output Plugins!
Parsing config file "/etc/snort/barnyard2.conf"


+[ Signature Suppress list ]+
----------------------------
+[No entry in Signature Suppress List]+
----------------------------
+[ Signature Suppress list ]+

Barnyard2 spooler: Event cache size set to [2048] 
ERROR: Can not get write access to logging directory "/var/log/barnyard2". (directory doesn't exist or permissions are set incorrectly or it is not a directory at all)
Fatal Error, Quitting..
Barnyard2 exiting
```

and permission is:

```
[root@localhost snort]# ls -l /var/log/barnyard2 
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug 14 16:35 /var/log/barnyard2
```

in this link this problem was solved but i don't understand how ...
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/barnyard2-start-service-error.51378/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a file, not a directory. There's a '-', not a 'd' in the first column of your ls output.

Comment: True. And the permissions are incorrect.